# How to assign very large outputs to function for evaluation at points?

Tags: functions, function-construction

I create a very large output

```
    D[x^100*E^(2*x^5)*Cos[x^2], {x, 137}]
```

I want to assign this to a function as

```
    f[x_]:= {very large output from previous command}
```

This allows me to evaluate that output for various values of $x$.

I tried

```
    Function[x, Evaluate[%11]]
```

But it seems cumbersome and I wasn't sure I was getting correct results from it.

Is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what [immediate assignments](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) are for:

```
f[x_] = D[x^100*E^(2*x^5)*Cos[x^2], {x, 137}]
(*    long output (can be suppressed with semicolon)    *)

f[3.]
(*    -8.90666869434476*10^664    *)
```

[See here](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/39-immediate-and-delayed-values.html) for a tutorial on the distinction between `=` and `:=`.

Comment: Rats! I had been using f[x_]:= for so long, that didn't even dawn on me! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f1[x_] = D[x^100*E^(2*x^5)*Cos[x^2], {x, 137}];

f2[x_] = D[x^100*E^(2*x^5)*Cos[x^2], {x, 137}] // Simplify;
```

While defining `f2` takes much longer,

```
LeafCount /@ {f1[x], f2[x]}

(* {4274535, 6386} *)

AbsoluteTiming[#[3.]] & /@ {f1, f2}

(* {{1.07832, -8.90666869434476*10^664}, 
    {0.002447, -8.906668694344757*10^664}} *)
```

Comment: You always give such nice answer - I enjoy reading them.